# Error in node/child in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I use node child to create a tree as follows.

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw, inner sep=3pt, minimum size=5pt] (r){$S$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (a) {}
        child {node [$\vdots$] 
                child {node [circle,draw] (d) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
                child {node [circle,draw] (e) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
            }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But I got error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted. };Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this node. };
```

I need help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always provide a compilable MWE.

In your code, `node[$\vdots$]` is the culprit, as `$\vdots$` is not a valid option for a node. It rather should be `node{$\vdots$}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle,draw, inner sep=3pt, minimum size=5pt] (r){$S$}
    child {node [circle,draw] (a) {}
        child {node {$\vdots$}
                child {node [circle,draw] (d) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
                child {node [circle,draw] (e) {$\frac{n}{2^k}$}}
            }
        }; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```